# Back press or finish() does not work in closing the activity

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an Android app that constantly receives data over Bluetooth and pushes data from `MainActivity` to `MainActivity2` through `Intent`. The `MainActivity` has an `ImageButton` that allows switching to the `MainActivity2`.

I am using a variable `Clicked` which is `true` when the `ImageButton` is clicked and `false` when `onBackpressed()`. I use the the `true/false` condition to start the Bluetooth receiving when I click on an `ImageButton`. I am able to receive the Bluetooth data in `MainActivity2`, but `onBackpressed` closes the `MainActivity2` returning to `MainActivity`. Then, as soon as a new data arrives, it automatically starts `MainActivity2` again.
I want that `MainActivity2` gets the data only when I click `ImageButton` and `onBackPressed`, `MainActivity2` is permanently closed, but it does not happen.

**MainActivity - ImgButtonFunction**

```
public void onImgButtClick(View view){
    Intent getNameScreenIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    final int result=1;
    Clicked=true;

    startActivityForResult(getNameScreenIntent,result);
}
```

**MainActivity - small part of data receive handler**

```
if (action.equals(UartService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE)) {

    final byte[] txValue = intent.getByteArrayExtra(UartService.EXTRA_DATA);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String text = new String(txValue, "UTF-8");
                /*Character[] Chararray = new Character[text.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                    Chararray[i] = new Character(text.charAt(i));
                }*/

                /*  Character[] Chararray = new Character[text.length()];
                    byte txByte=0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < txValue.length(); i++) {
                    Chararray[i] = new Character(text.charAt(i));}
                */

                String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                /*for (String retval: text.split("\n")) {
                    Chararray[i]=retval;
                    listAdapter.add("[" + currentDateTimeString + "] RecvX: " + retval + "km/h");
                }*/            

                String  str1 = String.valueOf(txValue[0]);
                listAdapter.add("[" + currentDateTimeString + "] RecvX: " +str1 + "km/h");
                messageListView.smoothScrollToPosition(listAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                if (Clicked==true) {
                    Intent ii = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                    ii.putExtra("RxString", str1);
                    startActivity(ii);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**MainActivity2 - onBackPressed handler**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Clicked",false);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While starting activity2 please start it by startActivityByResult()

In `onBackPressed()` do `setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("clicked", false))` and call finish()

In your activity1, you can get result in

```
onActivityResult()
```

Comment: actually in may mainActivity there is already an onActivityResult() which receives results from a third activity.

Comment: It does not matter from how many activities an activity is getting result back as long as you are starting an activity with a distinct request id. Use this request id to in onActivityResult to filter out incoming results.  You can Google some examples related to it.